# Arduino Mega with 5500 Ethernet Module, Websockets Disconnect regularly after receiving two messages

Tags: websocket, arduino

I have an Arduino Mega with a 5500 Ethernet module I have connecting to a web app using web sockets. There is two-way information. From the app I get JSON files that I can parse through and sort out the data I need and to the app I send a string that it will use to perform actions.

So far things look good other then it seems that the Websocket connection is disconnecting and reconnecing regularly.

```
Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:
  DHCP assigned IP 192.168.1.3
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text: 
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
Received text:
Received text:
Disconnected from WebSocket server!
Connected to WebSocket server!
```

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);
IPAddress myDns(192, 168, 0, 1);

WebSocketsClient ws;

// Variables to measure the speed
unsigned long beginMicros, endMicros;
unsigned long byteCount = 0;
bool printWebData = true;  // set to false for better speed measurement

//A string to concat the socketData together
String socketData;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
  switch(type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
       Serial.println("Disconnected from WebSocket server!");
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED: {
        Serial.println("Connected to WebSocket server!");
      }
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      socketData = (char * )payload;
      //parser(socketData);
      Serial.println("Received text: ");
      /* for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
      } */
      // send data to all connected clients
      //webSocket.sendTXT()
      // wsServer.broadcastTXT(payload, length);
      break;
    case WStype_BIN:
      Serial.println("Received binary data from server");
      break;
    case WStype_ERROR:
      Serial.println("WebSocket Error!");
      break;    
        case WStype_FRAGMENT_TEXT_START:
            socketData = (char * )payload;
            //USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Fragment Text Start: %s\n", payload);
            //USE_SERIAL.println(socketData);
            //USE_SERIAL.println("WStype_FRAGMENT_TEXT_START");
            break;
        case WStype_FRAGMENT_BIN_START:
        case WStype_FRAGMENT:
            socketData += (char * )payload;
            break;
        case WStype_FRAGMENT_FIN:
            socketData += (char * )payload; 
            //parser(socketData);
            //USE_SERIAL.println(socketData);
            break;
        case WStype_PONG:
            //USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] WStype_PONG: Ping reply\n");
      Serial.println("PONG");

            break;
        case WStype_PING:
            //USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] WStype_PONG: Ping reply\n");
      Serial.println("PING");

            break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  // You can use Ethernet.init(pin) to configure the CS pin
  Ethernet.init(53);  // Most Arduino shields

  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  Serial.println("Initialize Ethernet with DHCP:");
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // Check for Ethernet hardware present
    if (Ethernet.hardwareStatus() == EthernetNoHardware) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet shield was not found.  Sorry, can't run without hardware. :(");
      while (true) {
        delay(1); // do nothing, no point running without Ethernet hardware
      }
    }
    if (Ethernet.linkStatus() == LinkOFF) {
      Serial.println("Ethernet cable is not connected.");
    }
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, myDns);
  } else {
    Serial.print("  DHCP assigned IP ");
    Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);

  ws.begin("192.168.1.187", 8080, "ws://192.168.1.187:8080/panels/scoring/red/websocket");
  //webSocket.begin("10.0.100.5", 8080, "ws://10.0.100.5:8080/match_play/websocket");
  ws.onEvent(webSocketEvent);

}

unsigned long previousMillis = 0; 

// constants won't change:
const long interval = 1000; 

void loop() {
  ws.loop();
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    ws.sendTXT("{\"type\":\"R\"}");

  }

}
```

I did struggle to get a websockets library functioning on the AVR platform It seems I needed an older version of the library so I downloaded the Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/tree/ATmega tree from github and manually added it to my PlatforIO project.

Do I need to manualy respond with a hearbeat?
Is the Sever shutting the connection down or is the Arduino?

Comment: I been digging further into this and since I have access to the sever been trying to debug the difference from a working connection to this connection. What I have found is the Arduino is generating a Bad mask error on the server side.